What (if any) proof need a traveler have with them with the UK ETA
In the near future EU citizens will need to apply for an ETA when traveling to the UK. I was asked if you can (from then on) only travel to the UK if you have a smartphone on which you can show the proof you have applied and are approved for the ETA.
The person in case does not have a smartphone.
I found this UK site where I see nothing about needing to proove you are approved for the ETA. It does mention having to travel with the same passport but no other requirements. I would like to confirm this with more sites or experiences.

According to https://www.gov.uk/guidance/apply-for-an-electronic-travel-authorisation-eta#after-you-apply , the ETA is "linked to the passport you used to apply". This suggests to me that all you need is your passport. When they scan your passport their screen will show them that you have an ETA.
This doesn't address the aspect where you might have to demonstrate to the airline that you will be allowed to travel; however that same page says you will get an email saying you were approved. Printing that email and bringing it with you would seem like a good plan.
That page links to this video which says pretty much the same thing at the timestamp I constructed into the link.

This blog discusses how ETA will work. Although AFAIK having a valid ETA won’t ”demonstrate to the airline that you will be allowed in”, only that the holder has an advance permission to travel.

yes, ok, technically all these things (even visas) aren't proof you will be allowed in but proof you have permission to present yourself and request admission; i made a small edit.

Over 20 years ago when Australia introduced ETAs airlines were able to look up ETAs of passengers. Since then similar systems have been set up for many other countries (notably the US ESTA), in most cases it will be automatic based on API data, they will only ask questions if the system does not come up with a valid ETA (and you are not a UK citizen and similar situations). With the replacement of BRPs with eVisas the same will apply to residents, I suppose.

The ETA is linked to your passport number (like ETAs in Australia, ESTAs in the US, eTAs in Canada, etc.).
When you travel to the UK by air, you have to submit “API” data (Advance Passenger Information), which notably includes your passport country and number.
This will allow the airline to look up if you have an ETA automatically. You shouldn’t need to show anything but your passport as long as you have a valid ETA attached to the passport and you show the right passport, they will just know.
If travelling via Eurostar, juxtaposed controls mean you will be checked by UK officers directly before boarding, and again, the passport is enough.
I believe the same applies for the Eurotunnel Shuttle.
For ferries I think it depends on the route, I guess one of the two methods will apply.
However this means that if your passport gets replaced (lost, stolen or expired), you will need to update your ETA (or apply for a new one, didn’t check).
